# How to scroll smoothly using Gesture Detector

Tags: android, scroll

when I draw bitmap + canvas the scroller scroll very slow  and i am using Gesture Detector to scroll.How to solve this problem.Here is on Touch method

```
 @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("onTouch");
        if (!enabled) {
            System.out.println("enabled");
            return false;
        }

        boolean retVal = scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        retVal = gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event) || retVal;
        System.out.println("retVal"+retVal);


        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            System.out.println("action up");
            if (scrolling) {
                scrolling = false;
                onScrollEnd(event);
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

This is my on scroll method

```
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    System.out.println("onScroll");
    scrolling = true;
    if (pdfView.isZooming() || pdfView.isSwipeEnabled()) {
        pdfView.moveTo(-distanceX,-distanceY,true);
    }
    return true;
}
```

In this method I am checking all the condition and scrolling is working from here

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public void moveTo(float offsetX, float offsetY, boolean moveHandle) {
    if (swipeVertical) {
        float scaledPageWidth = toCurrentScale(pdfFile.getMaxPageWidth());
        System.out.println("scaled"+scaledPageWidth+" width "+getWidth());
        if (scaledPageWidth < getWidth()) {
            offsetX = getWidth() / 2 - scaledPageWidth / 2;
            System.out.println("scaledPageWidth < getWidth()");
        } else {
            if (offsetX > 0) {
                System.out.println("offsetX > 0");
                offsetX = 0;
                setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        // Check Y offset
        float contentHeight = pdfFile.getDocLen(zoom);
        if (contentHeight < getHeight()) {
            offsetY = (getHeight() - contentHeight) / 2;
        } else {
            if (offsetY > 0) {
                offsetY = 0;
                setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);

            }

        }

}
```

Comment: bring code, my friend . . .

Comment: implement onFling for smooth scrolling.it uses animation also

Comment: Sorry for commenting late. @Anmol I have already applied animation in onFling but its not wokring smoothly

Comment: is animation not working smooth?

Comment: @Anmol no its not working smooth

Answer (score 1):

To get a smooth result for scrolling in XY axis using Gesture Detector you will have to implement

`boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,...)`

as per your use case(bitmap case have to get diffX,diffY from view and map it to your bitmap).

I also used `onFling` to have a translation animation to view when user fling's to scroll (as in case of list view).

[reference](https://en.proft.me/2017/06/25/detecting-gestures-android-gesturedetector/)